# Magento 2 how to create custom tabs in custom module

Tags: magento2, module, custom, tabs

We want to remove default product tab and want to use custom

Query tabbing like this

[image]

Comment: You want to remove any one tab?

Comment: Do you want to add your custom tabs in frontend product detail page?

Comment: Yes we will remove default tab and will use Custom tab as in screenshot